# Can't do Google UK searches with Firefox Search Box when HTTPS Everywhere is active

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, https, google-search

When [HTTPS Everywhere 2.0.2](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) extension is active, searches in the built-in Firefox Search Box go to https://encrypted.google.com (instead of https://www.google.co.uk as desired).  This means that I can't get UK results without having to go to https://www.google.co.uk manually and type my search term.

Is there any easy way to get the Firefox Search Box to send searches to https://www.google.co.uk?

Using Firefox 11.0 on XP SP 3.

Comment: Have you tried [filing a bug report](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/report/19)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  However, I'm using my work-around below for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by going to the HTTPS Everywhere Preferences.  In the rules, search for "Google".  There is a rule called "Search www.google.com", which is currently unselected by default.  Select this rule and press "OK".  Searches in the Firefox search bar now show results from https://www.google.co.uk as desired.